# Inconsistent definitions of magnetic remanence

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

On the["Remanence" article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remanence) we find the definition:

> Remanence or remanent magnetization or residual magnetism is the magnetization left behind in a ferromagnetic material (such as iron) after an external magnetic field is removed.

But the same article also features the following image:

[image]

subtitled: "$B_r$ denotes remanence", where $B_r$ is clearly the intercept with the $H=0$ axis.

---

I think both definitions ($B$ remaining after external fields are removed VERSUS $B$ at $H=0$) are incompatible. Here are my arguments (illustration from ["Magnetic field" article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) to help visualization):

[image]

1. Consider a permanent magnet in vacuum far from all sources of current. It produces a magnetic flux density field $\vec B$ outside — which is due to the magnetization after external magnetic fields have been removed (according to one definition, the remanent magnetism). By definition, it also produces a magnetic field $\vec H = \vec B/\mu_0$ outside. If we take the line integral of $\vec H$ along a loop that passes both inside and outside the magnet, by Ampère's law $\oint\vec H\cdot d\vec\ell=0$ (there is no current), we conclude that $\int_{\rm in} \vec H\cdot d\vec\ell=-\int_{\rm out}\vec H\cdot d\vec\ell$.

If $\vec H=\vec 0$ inside the magnet, then we must have $\int_{\rm out} \vec H\cdot d\vec\ell=0$. But this is definitely not the case if the field of the bar magnet is that of a pure dipole (see below), and I conjecture that it cannot be the case for any volume distribution of dipole, quadripole... densities inside the magnet. So $H\not=0$ inside the magnet, as depicted above, and the remanent $\vec B$ is not the $\vec B$ at $H=0$

2. The case of a sphere with uniform magnetization $\vec M$. It has the field of a perfect dipole outside, but a uniform flux density field $\vec B=\frac23\mu_0\vec M$ inside (Griffiths Example 6.1), and hence, a magnetic field $\vec H = \vec B/\mu_0-\vec M = -\frac13\vec M$ inside (compatible with Ampère's law). So again, even though this would be an example of a magnetic field from prior magnetization, it is not the $H=0$ intercept (because $H\not=0$ inside the sphere). This is actually a concrete case of the previous argument.

---

**Question:** Is the above reasoning correct and there is confusion/conflation between two incompatible definitions of remanence? I think this is the case, probably, I guess, because *in practice* the difference between the two is negligible, but still, conceptually I think it's an important distinction. Or, is the above reasoning incorrect, and if so, why?

---

**Appendix:** I was led to consider this when reading Fitzgerald "Electric Machinery", Example 1.9, where we study the case of a magnetic circuit consisting of a permanent magnet and a magnetic core to direct the field to a small air gap. Assuming $\mu_{\rm core}=\infty$, applying Ampère's law (and the usual simplifications of magnetic circuits) around the circuit we obtain $H_{\rm magnet}l_{\rm magnet}+H_{\rm gap}l_{\rm gap}=0$; then rewrite $H_{\rm gap}=B_{\rm gap}/\mu_0$, claim that $B_{\rm magnet}=B_{\rm gap}$ (because $\oiint \vec B\cdot d\vec a=0$ and leakage flux neglected) and obtain

$$
H_{\rm magnet} = -\frac{l_{\rm gap}}{l_{\rm magnet}}\frac{B_{\rm magnet}}{\mu_0}
$$

This equation relating $B,H$ inside the magnet must then be compared with the $BH$ curve of the material. The intersection between the two, which gives the solution for the fields, will be the in the top-left quadrant ($B>0,H<0$), and if the material has sufficiently low coercivity (soft magnetic material), it will be seen that the resulting $B$ will be much smaller than $B|_{H=0}$.

Thus I concluded that $B|_{H=0}$ could not in fact be the magnetic field after all external sources have been removed (which I now identify with $B|_{I=0}$), because this would mean that the presence of the magnetic core near the magnet would demagnetize the magnet, which is absurd; given the flux-confining nature of the core, the flux density field $B$ at the gap should be higher than in the absence of the core -- exactly the opposite effect.

In other words, the presence of the core **reduces** the total reluctance of the circuit (when compared to air surrounding everything), and so it must **increase** the flux density. And so the original flux density cannot be equal to $B|_{H=0}$, since that is greater than the flux density after the core has been placed.